# Tomcat in Eclipse logs

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, catalina.out

guys.
I've a Tomcat 9 in an Eclipse 2023/12 installation in Windows. I use the workspace metadata for tomcat server location. How find where the catalina.out is writing?
I need to read that file for search into it old messages erased on the console.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check under your workspace's `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core` folder once the server is launched. We can't be sure what the exact directory name is since it can vary based on a number of factors.

Comment: Under that directory there is the logs directory, but only contains the localhost_access_logs, not the catalina.out